# Is $GL(r,\mathbb{C})$ diffeomorphic to direct product of $U(n)$ and euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Can some one give a reference/proof of the following (possibly positive) result?

> $GL(r,\mathbb{C})$ is diffeomorphic to $U(n)$ and Euclidean space.

This is a (possible) special case of Iwasawa theorem

> If $G$ is a connected Lie group, then $G$ is diffeomorphic to direct product of a maximal compact subgroup $H$ and Eucldiean space.

Here $Gl(r,\mathbb{C})$ is connected Lie group, $U(n)$ is maximal compact  subgroup. So, it seems  $GL(r,\mathbb{C})$ is diffeomorphic to $U(n)$ and Euclidean space. Can an easy proof/reference be given for this?

Comment: I think the theorem should say "direct product of a maximal **compact** subgroup and Euclidean space" (and then it holds trivially for a compact group with the Euclidean space being zero-dimensional).

Comment: See the discussion under "Topology" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup.

Comment: @RobArthan that was my mistake,, corrected it.. thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Iwasawa theorem is not terribly easy, to my recollection. If you change your statement as in Rob Arthan's comment, it is correct. But for most of the classical groups you are probably interested in, there are simple proofs, as in the following (your specific case).

Let $\mathcal H_n$ be the space of positive Hermitian forms on $\Bbb C^n$; this is a convex open subset of the space of $n \times n$ Hermitian (that is, complex self-adjoint) matrices. This space has real dimension $n^2$; any convex open subset of a real vector space of dimension $k$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^k$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/212595/40804) for a more complicated proof of a more general fact).

The group $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ acts smoothly on $\mathcal H_n$ by pullback of forms (or if you're thinking of these as matrices, it acts by conjugation). It acts transitively because every $n$-dimensional complex Hilbert space is isomorphic, so given $H, H' \in \mathcal H_n$, there must be some isomorphism $A: (\Bbb C^n, H) \to (\Bbb C^n, H')$; this isomorphism is $A \in GL_n(\Bbb C)$. If we write $g$ for the standard inner product corresponding to the diagonal matrix, the stabilizer of $g$ is $U(n)$ (by definition!). So $\mathcal H_n$ is a homogeneous space, and hence sits into a principal bundle $$U(n) \to GL_n(\Bbb C) \to GL_n(\Bbb C)/U(n) \cong \mathcal H_n \cong \Bbb R^{n^2}.$$ Because every bundle over a contractible space is smoothly trivial, we can find a ($U(n)$-equivariant!) diffeomorphism $GL_n(\Bbb C) \cong U(n) \times \Bbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the statement. It was a typo :) I need some time to understand this. Thanks thanks

Comment: Can you please give a reference where Iwasawa theorem is proved... Ofcourse original paper has the proof :D.. I am looking for some recent exposition... :)

Comment: It should be in Hochschild's book on Lie groups. I mostly don't remember it. It's not hard at the level of Lie algebras, but the global result is interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it... Can you have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051220/chern-class-cohomology-coefficients-complex-real-integral